# Avoid user registrations with specific email provider

Tags: filters, user-registration

I have been under a spam attack, someone is creating a lot of users daily, it could be a bot, all those users have the same email provider, is there any way in which I can avoid that anyone creates a user using a specific email provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this hook: [`register_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/register_post)

```
add_action('register_post', 'ban_email_2334', 10, 3);

function ban_email_2334( $username, $email, $errors ){

    $result = array();

    // check if email is from the provider you wish to ban
    preg_match('/bannedprovider.com/i', $email, $result);

    if( !empty( $result )){
        $errors->add('spam_email', __( 'Some choicest abuses you might want to pass on' ));
    }

    return;

}
```

This will throw an error and prevent registration

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to use a plugin I think:

[Ban Hammer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ban-hammer/) provides the functionality you require.